# JS Disable drag and drop (draggable attribute)

Tags: javascript, draggable

Using [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) method, I have some elements on my page that can be dragged from one column to another.

I would like to be able to make the drag permanent. That is, once an element is dragged (or dropped I guess) ONCE, it can no longer be dragged.

I tried setting draggable to false using `setAttribute`, but that didn't seem to work.

So how could you (using plain old JS, no jQuery stuff) disable the draggable ability of an element?

I actually searched this and only found stuff about disabling dragging and dropping of files and other stuff onto a page, that is not what I am asking about. Thanks in advance.

Comment: setting draggable to false works for me. Try debugging your setAttribute approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the W3Schools page you referenced - past this into the console:

```
document.getElementById('drag1').setAttribute('draggable',false);
```

Then try to drag the element. I think you'll find it works ;)

If you provide your code, I will help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding `ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;"` in the html tag to disable the drag & drop.
Hope this will help you :)